# LightSwitch w/ Silverlight DesktopClient - How to change DB where permissions are stored

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LightSwitch HTMLClient application built in VS2013 and a SQL database project used to publish to an external database.

I'm using Windows authentication instead of Forms authentication for my authentication and I'm attempting to use a Silverlight DesktopClient as my user authorisation/permissions client.

From my research I've read that the Silverlight DesktopClient that I'm trying to use for my permissions uses the intrinsic database within the application but I would like to store the permissions in my external database specified by my database project.

I'm also using WIX as my deployment tool so the inbuilt LightSwitch publish tool isn't an option.

There are three parts to what I would like to achieve that I just can't seem to work out:

1. Setup an AD group that contains users that are in the default SecurityAdministation permission group
2. Specify the above AD group in the Web.config file so that I can later customise it via msi transform
3. Setup the Silverlight DesktopClient to point at my external SQL database to store and manage users, roles and permission

How would I go about achieving these three parts?

Thanks in advance!